# prometheus: are there some benefits to use counter if I also use histogram for the same kind of metric?

Tags: prometheus, metrics

For example imagine that we need to measure two metrics: requests number (counter) and request duration (histogram). Histogram already has inner counter, so when I what to query requests rate I can use histogram metric instead of counter.

Are there some benefits for using separate counter metric?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there *is* a benefit of using an additional counter: naming. Say you have a histogram named `http_request_duration_seconds`, the associated counter is named `http_request_duration_seconds_count`, whereas `http_requests_total` would be a much better name.